# SQL - How to pivot and combine data across rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, pivot

Am tyring to model on a dataset with individual person's vitals for a wellness app, imagine like Fitbit. However, these vitals, for a given person are recorded and reported as individual rows. E.g.

```
TableName: PersonalVitals

PersonID | RecordedTime | VitalType | VitalValue 
   1     |    17:10     |   HR      |    72bpm       <- Heart rate
   1     |    17:10     |   RR      |    19insp/min  <- Respiratory rate
   2     |    15:35     |   RR      |    11insp/min  <- Respiratory rate
   1     |    17:15     |   HR      |    76bpm       <- Heart rate
```

Now, on extraction, I need to pivot this data, so that all the vitals that were taken during the same time, are reported together, something like below

```
PersonID | RecordedTime |   HR   |   RR        |  SpO2   |  BP(Blood Pressure)
   1     |    17:10     |  72bpm | 19insp/min  |  null   |    null
   1     |    17:15     |  76bpm |    null     |  null   |    null  
   2     |    15:35     |  null  | 11insp/min  |  null   |    null
```

How can I achive the above in SQL (sql-server or postgres)?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your code so far please?

Comment: Is the list of vital types fixed? (There is no `SpO2` in your sample data)

Comment: This list of vitals is fixed, albiet a somewhat big list, so I have just curated the above example to show few of the vitals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Postgres I would aggregate all vitals into a single JSONB value and then extract them as columns:

```
select person_id, 
       recorded_time, 
       vitals ->> 'HR' as "HR", 
       vitals ->> 'RR' as "RR", 
       vitals ->> 'SpO2' as "SpO2", 
       vitals ->> 'BP' as "Blood Pressure"
from (
  select person_id, recorded_time, 
         jsonb_object_agg(vital_type, vital_value) as vitals
  from person_vitals 
  group by person_id, recorded_time
) t
order by person_id, recorded_time;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/ONNU50709

As with all pivot solutions, you will need to change the query if you add new vital types. With the above solutions, it's enough to do that in the outer query. The inner query does not need to be changed.

If the code processing that result can deal with a JSON value, I would just return the result of the inner query directly, rather than turning that into individual columns.

Comment: This solution is great, but requires upfront knowledge of vitals so that they can be added in 'select' list of outer query. If, however, the list of vitals is not known, then how can the above query be amended to list all the vitals that are returned from the inner query as individual columns?

Comment: @sppc42: if the list of vitals is not know, you can't amend that query to deal with that. One of the restrictions of SQL is, that the number of columns (and their data types) has to be know to the database **before** actually executing the query. The only way to get that in a "dynamic" way is to return the JSON value from the inner query to your application and deal with the "pivot" part in the front end (which is almost always the better choice anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Using Pivot

```
SELECT PersonID , RecordedTime,[HR],[RR] ,SpO2,[BP(Blood Pressure)]
FROM
(
SELECT * ,NULL AS  SpO2,NULL AS [BP(Blood Pressure)]
FROM #PersonalVitals
)
As Src
PIVOT
(
MAX(VitalValue) FOR VitalType IN ([HR],[RR]))AS Pvt
ORDER BY PersonID
```